# Can I use matchPath without a child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Let's say I have this component with `myCurrentState` with a value being 0.
And I would like to change it to 1 when I am being routed to `ConfirmComponent`(/) and back to 0 when routing back to `RootComponent`(/confirm)

```
class MySpecialComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    ...
  }
}

state = {
  myCurrentState: 0,
};

<Router>
  <div>
    <Route
      path="/"
      render={() => <RootComponent />}
      exact
    />
    <Route path="/confirm" render={() => <ConfirmComponent />} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Most examples (matchPath, match) that I could find were examples with adding code into the child components. But I would like to do this all in this main `MySpecialComponent` component.

Could somebody give me examples if this is possible and if so, then how :)?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to add code to the child components? If not, you could call a function from the child in the constructor (passed in as a prop from MySpecialComponent) to change the state

Comment: Maybe because of my lack of knowledge in react still, but I cannot figure out how to do that inside a child if I do not have an onClick event there.
For example in the RootComponent I am using <NavLink to="/confirm"><button type="button">Continue
          </button>
        </NavLink>... Did not feel like it would be correct place where to add a state change.

Comment: It just feels weird, because I want to know the path inside the parent, why should a child component care what is my current path :D

Comment: Is it fine to have an onClick attribute inside a <button> that is inside the NavLink - if this is normal way, then I probably will have to go this way

Comment: don't put it in the onClick, put it in the constructor of the child. the child component that is rendered depends on the path, and you can pass different props in depending on the path. I will post an example below

Answer (score 0):

Like we discussed in the comments, if you are fine with adding code in the child, this is a possible solution

```
class MySpecialComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    ...
  }

changeValue = (value) => {
  this.setState({myCurrentState: value});
}

state = {
  myCurrentState: 0,
};

render = () => <Router>
  <div>
    <Route
      path="/"
      render={() => <ConfirmComponent updateParentState={() => this.changeValue(1)}/>}
      exact
    />
    <Route path="/confirm" render={() => <RootComponent updateParentState={() => this.changeValue(0)} />} />
  </div>
</Router>;
}
```

FYI I think you may have Root and Confirm components mixed up in your example according to what you want to do.

In child components

```
class RootComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.props.updateParentState(); //updates state of parent
  }
  ...
}
class ConfirmComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.props.updateParentState(); //updates state of parent
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Will try this out in a minute ;)
Not mixed :p I just used some random naming to make it more generic :D As in root and / and confirm with /confirm

Comment: And in the nav bar I display the current active step (root or confirmation and that is why the values are 0 and 1 based on the fact in which component is being open atm)

Comment: Nice, it does work! :)
But now I realized that I am not using matchPath :D Is the suggested approach better than using reactRouter `match`?

Comment: You'll have to decide that for yourself, but this is how I would do it. I am not too familiar with match and matchPath, and after a brief look at the documentation I don't really see the point